# Running each JUnit test in a separate JVM in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I have a project with nearly 500 individual tests in around 200 test classes. Some of these tests don't do a great job of tearing down their own state after they're finished, and in Eclipse this results in some tests failing. The tests all pass when running the test suite from the command line via Ant.

Can I enable 'test isolation' somehow in Eclipse? I don't mind if it takes longer to run.

Long term, I will clean up the misbehaving tests, but in the short term I'd like to get the tests working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Ant in Eclipse, you can set the JUnit task to fork a new JVM process for each test, providing isolation.

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html

Comment: It will only fork one new JVM for the entire test suite, not one for each single test.

Comment: @Michael - if the forkmode attribute is set to "perTest" then a new JVM should be created for each test - this is the default.

Comment: The link appears broken -- try this one: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html

Comment: Ohh, it worked when I first answered this -- I'll edit my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution I found to execute every test class in its own JVM:

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                    <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

> forkCount=1/reuseForks=false executes each test class in its own JVM process, one after another. It creates the highest level of separation for the test execution, but it would probably also give you the longest execution time of all the available options. Consider it as a last resort. [[1](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html)]

This solves the problem for me when running the tests outside of intellij directly with `mvn test`, unfortunately IntelliJ doesn't respect this.

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar needs and developed [small maven plugin Jute](https://github.com/raydac/jute) which has been published in maven central. It starts external JVM process for each JUnit test method.

Comment: He wants to run them in eclipse. I presume like me he would like to see the unit tests results in the JUnit tab. He already stated that he's using Ant not Maven - Ant already lets you run tests in the way he wants.