# JUnit-Test differs between class and project testing

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit, hsqldb

I'm hitting a strange error related to unit-testing in my Java application.

During unit-testing I use in-memory HSQLDB pre-filled with custom data (via an Insert script triggered automatically) and Hibernate as ORM to access it.

Problem is following, if I start the unit-test on a single class (i.e.: TestDummyClass.java) the db is recreated (from the original insert script) **after each method test**.

If I launch the unit-test on the whole project (src/test) which contains multiple test classes, the DB is initialize on the beginning for each test-class and not on each test-method.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:com/wizche/app-context-test.xml" })
public class TestDummyClass {
.....
}
```

This means for example that if in TestDummyClass I change the DB (i.e. creating a new object) in some test-method the new object will stay there for the following test-methods in the same class. Therefore the asserts should differs if I start it on the project or on the single class!

Can someone explain me why is this happening? How can I decide when to restore the clean-db?

NB: I'm using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner with a custom context configuration for the whole test-project (in which there is no parameter related to unit-testing).
NB2: I start JUnit direct in SpringEclipse

Comment: Could you please provide the configuration (annotations) of the test class? Do you use @DirtiesContext? I'd suppose this is a direction you need to look.

Comment: No I don't, I just updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that if you use SpringJUnit4ClassRunner, it tends to cache the application context if you use the exact same location for multiple tests - this caching is across a suite so if you execute all the tests in your project in a single suite, and use the same application context location across multiple tests, it is likely that you will get a cached context - and if you modify beans in a context, that will reflect for other tests too.

A fix is to add `@DirtiesContext` annotation to the test class or test method

Comment: If I add the @DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD) it does regenerate the db after each test-method on both running type (single class/project). But my goal would be that for both testing the db is regenerated on beginning for each class. Is it possible? The real solution to my problem is to add the DirtiesContext on all my 120 test-classes? (seems a workaround to me)

Comment: Not necessarily for all your tests - if your test modifies a context then you need to add @DirtiesContext, to indicate to Spring to remove it from the cache. Also, if you simply use a different context file, a new cache entry will be created for the different context. I may have misunderstood your comment though.

Comment: The only remaining question marks is why if I start the a single UT on a class it keeps regenerate a DB after each test-method (disregarding if I stated @DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS) or I remove the @DirtiesContext annotation completely). The desired behaviour for both is that the DB is generated one time only during setUp().

Comment: Yes, reading through the @DirtiesContext javadoc, it does that it is supposed to mark the context as dirty after the entire test class classMode=AFTER_CLASS , could be a bug if it is not working that way for you.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse runs unit tests in a single JVM so theoretically even running on a single class you should see the same behaviour as running from src/test. I'm thinking running all your tests your more likely to see a problem. What makes you sure the DB is recreated after each method when you a single class test - just want to make sure this is accurate?

A similar question has been raised before check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890259/running-each-junit-test-in-a-separate-jvm-in-eclipse) out. It will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I'm sure about this because I check the items in db using my DAOs, this means that a call to myDao.getAll() return different values if I started the test-class (lower value) alone or in the project (bigger value because of object created before the test-method I'm inspecting).

Comment: I don't see any other option for you except to rollback your transaction after each test. Not sure what version of Spring your using however try looking at the spring documentation on `@Transactional` and `@TestExecutionListeners` which will help. I believe `@DirtiesContext` (as others have pointed out) might help by providing the required test execution listeners, you must though annotation the class with `@Transactional`.

Comment: Actually with @DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD) I can force both single/project UT to regenerate the db after each method. My goal is that the DB is generated only at setUp() time, currently when I launch the single class UT it keep regenerating the DB after each test-method, independently of the DirtiesContext I'm setting (AFTER_CLASS or none), in some way single class tests behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) to assist with building & tearing down your database. It provides methods to do this on the fly and interacts with all the main database providers.