# JMockit @Mocked annotation causes other tests to fail

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit, jmockit

I have a project with 3 test classes - `TextModelTest`, `LocalClassificationTaskTest`, `ModelFetcherTest`.
When run individually, each of them pass, but when run all at once (from Eclipse), all tests of the third one (`ModelFetcherTest`) fail with a `NullPointerException`. Surprisingly, eclipse won't even stop at the breakpoint I put in the tested class (`ModelFetcher`).

After doing some research (tried to ignore each of the successful tests in order to find out which one caused the 3rd class to fail), I noticed that the second test class (`LocalClassificationTaskTest`) has a Mocked field of type `ModelFetcher`, which is the CUT of the 3rd test class:

```
@Mocked ModelFetcher modelFetcher;
```

In `ModelFetcherTest`:

```
@Tested ModelFetcher modelFetcher;
```

I removed the `@Mocked` annotation and replaced its logic with a `MockUp<ModelFetcher>` (which is more cumbersome and verbose, but whatever), and now everything works.

Note that the problem occurred only in eclipse. All the tests passed when ran by maven.
There is no race issue and all the tests pass and fail consistently (no luck involved).

Can the `@Mocked` annotation affect other tests cases within the same project?

Comment: You should show a [minimal version of those three test classes, which when executed in the "right" order reproduce the failure](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, there's no way for an actual answer to be provided.

Answer (score 0):

The only way the @Mocked annotation in one class could affect another class is if the jvm process is shared between the classes. Normally, each test class should fork a seperate jvm process, thus keeping the mocks isolated to their respective test class. It sounds like your test suite that runs all the tests together is running a single jvm. I don't use Eclipse, but [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890259/running-each-junit-test-in-a-separate-jvm-in-eclipse) seems to indicate that this has been a problem for others in Eclipse. You may be able to change your build scripts in Eclipse to fork a seperate jvm, though.

Comment: 10x, I checked out the thread and there's no clear-cut solution for forking JVMs from within Eclipse. Some more research suggests that it can't be done without a designated plugin. I'll check out and update.

Comment: For context, the default behavior for gradle is to run all tests in a single jvm https://discuss.gradle.org/t/tests-should-use-one-jvm-per-test-class-not-per-project/12774